# Setting up URL base for JSON with expressjs

Tags: json, node.js, express

I am completely new to node ExpressJS and am required to rewrite a rule for my server data source (jason format).

```
./
../public/
  /public/css
  /public/js
  /public/index.html

../datasource/
  /datasource/carmodel.json
```

The default static directories are set in:

```
 app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../public'));
```

The above work and everything runs under the 3000 port fine locally.

I need to rewrite the URL for my json file (datasource/carmodel.json) by replacing `datasource` with `car/models/`.  However my application is unable to find the /datasource/carmodel.json file. I have attempted to recreate this via the following:

```
app.use('car/models/', require('./../datasource/'));
```

But I still cannot find the json source URL. It does not matter if I type: `http://localhost:3000/car/models/carmodel.json` or `http://localhost:3000/datasource/carmodel.json` for that matter. Is there something I am missing?

```
------------------
     EDITED
------------------
```

Please see my project structure:

```
./
 node_modules/
 public/
        css/
           custom.css
        js/
          app.js (angular)
        index.html
 datasource/
            carmodel.json
            index.js (express file)
 package.json
 README
```

Currently my static folder is running of localhost:3000/. Contents of datasource/index.js:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

//json
app.get('/car/models/:filename', function(req, res){
  var filename = req.params.filename;
  var fileDir = 'server/' + filename;
  res.download(fileDir);
})

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('App started on port 3000!');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check something like this:

```
app.get('/car/models/:filename', function(req, res){
  var filename = req.params.filename;
  var fileDir = __dirname + '/datasource/' + filename;
  res.download(fileDir);
})
```

then this http://localhost:3000/car/models/carmodel.json should work. I dont test it, youst write from head, therefore there may be some typos.

My solution is not safe. You shoud validate 'filename' before production use (all data from user must be validated).

Comment: Thanks but it does not work. My local server does not seem to find the "datasource" directory as it lives outside of my static folder (public). I can't even browser to localhost:3000/datasource/carmodel.json as it cannot find the file. I just want a way to map Express to this directory and mount it to /car/models/. Any ideas?

Comment: of course you cant get localhost:3000/datasource/carmodel.json. From express you can only get files from static directory or from routes. My solution show how to set route and then get file 'by server' and push it to browser. In this solution you can get all files to which your script has permission. I checked my code and it download file.
when you run server and go to  http://localhost:3000/car/models/carmodel.json in browser what is happening (it should download file or show it in browser)? Maybe you have wrong permission to this file?

Comment: in my code i make assumption that datasource is in project directory. But looking on your code it may be level up? If yes then change this "var fileDir = __dirname + '/datasource/' + filename;" to this "var fileDir = __dirname + '/../datasource/' + filename;"

Comment: It shoud show it in the browser as a static Json. I tried copying it under public/data/carmodel.json and it shows it in the browser fine. It is only a static file located on my machine under the datatsource/ directory in the project so I do not understand the permissions issue. Can't your script just pull the json file and replace its path with car/models/ making it accessible via the localhost:300/car/models/carmodel.json url?

Comment: Or it is indeed. I changed the default line " app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../public'));"  to : app.use(express.static('public')); as it was confusing me as well and it still runs under locahost:3000/. That is why I am not understanding how ExpressJS works, too much path confusion.

Comment: Please update your question and add structure of your project: base dir, public dir, datasource dir, server script, package.json, and script where you set my code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90695/discussion-between-hgb-and-krzysztof-sztompka).